# OpenGL drawing Inverted Triangle

Tags: c++, opengl

My triangle vertices are in array vertices that are specified in such a way that I should get an upright triangle but my triangle is inverted around y axis.
The code is below.

This is some Global stuff

```
#include<GL\glew.h>
#include<GL\freeglut.h>
#include<glm.hpp>
#include<gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1,-1,
    1,-1,
    0,1
};

GLuint vaoId;
GLuint vboId;

glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(50.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 5.0f, 
20.0f);
glm::mat4 modelViewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(0, 0, -20));

string parseShader(string fileName) {
    string shaderCode;
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(fileName, ios::in);
    string line;
    while (!ifs.eof()) {
        getline(ifs, line);
        shaderCode += line;
        shaderCode += "\n";
    }
    return shaderCode;
}

GLuint program;
```

This function just loads shaders

```
void loadShader() {
    string vShader = parseShader("vShader.txt");
    GLuint vShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const GLchar* vShaderSource = vShader.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vShaderId, 1, &vShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShaderId);
    GLint compileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(vShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);
    if (!compileStatus) {
        cout << "Cannot compile shader\n";
        glDeleteShader(vShaderId);
        return;
    }

    string fShader = parseShader("fShader.txt");
    GLuint fShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const GLchar* fShaderSource = fShader.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fShaderId, 1, &fShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShaderId);
    glGetShaderiv(fShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);
    if (!compileStatus) {
        cout << "Cannot compile fragment Shader\n";
        glDeleteShader(fShaderId);
        return;
    }

    GLuint programId;
    programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, vShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programId, fShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(programId);
    GLint linkStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    if (!linkStatus) {
        cout << "Cannot link program\n";
        glDeleteShader(vShaderId);
        glDeleteShader(fShaderId);
        glDeleteProgram(programId);
        return;
    }
    glUseProgram(programId);
}
```

This loads data in VBO

```
void loadDataInBuffers() {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

This function is used to bind states to VAO

```
void loadVao() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

This is rendering function

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This calls all other functions defined above

```
void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    loadDataInBuffers();
    loadShader();
    loadVao();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(1, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(2, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelViewMatrix[0][0]);
}
```

My main Method looks like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple Window");
    glewInit();
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the vertex Shader

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

void main(){
    vec4 position = vec4(pos,0,1);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*position;
}
```

Below is the Fragment Shader

```
#version 430

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

This is what I get
[image: THis is what I get when I draw the Triangle]

Shouldn't I get something like this
[image: Shouldn't I get something like this]

Comment: There are many ways to do this, depending on what you want to do. You could mess with your matrix, you could mess with the vertex data, you could hard-code a mirror in the vertex shader. It's kinda hard to answer without a bit more context.

Comment: You could post 2 screenshots: One of the actual result and one how it should look like (use paint). This way, we have more of an idea.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann I've edited my post and included images.

Comment: @Frank I guess vertex shader will receive vertices in order they were specified so by that my triangle should be upside down.

Comment: But what do you want to invert? The triangle itself? The final image? the way the triangle is transformed? The results are all the same, but the intent is very different.

Comment: @Frank I'm saying that the final image I should get should be something like the image above based on the matrices I've generated and my whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

It looks like you're running into the problem described here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185661-glm-perspective-inverts-image

```
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(50.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 5.0f, 20.0f);
```

You've specified the angle (50.0) in degrees; it should be in radians. 50 radians is a weird number and probably not what you want.

Apparently the units for this function are not well-documented (I can't get to the doc site, so I don't know). Replace 50.0 with whatever it is in radians and see if that works.

```
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(50.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 5.0f, 20.0f);
```

Comment: That makes the triangle disappear. My camera is at origin looking down towards negative Z-axis and my near and far clipping plane are 5 and 20 respectively. So I'm moving my triangle down on negative z axis so that it lies between near and far clipping plane.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is inverting the final image, the easiest way to accomplish that is to simply apply a mirror operation at the end of your vertex shader once the coordinates are in clip space:

```
gl_Position = (projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*position) * vec4(1, -1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Of course that will make it correct, but what I am saying is should I not get it  without mirror operation.